# In iOS if Model notifies View, does this break MVC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, model-view-controller, sdwebimage

I'm using SDWebImage(inside my Model) to asynchronously load user images, that are in UITableViewCells, when I create User(Model) objects. When image is being downloaded I show a NSActivityIndicator in place of image in tableviewcell(View). When image gets downloaded I reload my tableview. Because I put those NSActivityIndicators inside my cell, I have no other way to stop them but via Notifications(inside SDWEbimage method completion handler). **So the question is whether this is a right way to do this according to MVC architecture?**

Here's the snippet of my Model class(Employee):

```
    self.employeeID = [self stringValueForKey:@"id"];
    self.name = [self stringValueForKey:@"name"];
    self.company = [self stringValueForKey:@"company"];
    self.companyID = [self numberValueForKey:@"companyId"];
    self.photo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photoPlaceholder"];

    // fetch Emploee photo
    NSString *photoURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://blabla.com//img/photo/%@.png",self.employeeID];
    [[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoURL]
                                                          options:0
                                                         progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
     {
     } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished)
     {
         if (image && finished)
         {
             self.photo = image;

             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"IMAGE_FINISHED_DOWNLOADING" object:self];

             // make updates to database from Main Thread to avoid race conditions
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest new];
                [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EmployeeCD" inManagedObjectContext:[AppDelegate getDelegate].managedObjectContext]];
                NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"employeeID == %@",self.employeeID];
                [request setPredicate:predicate];

                NSError *err;
                NSArray *arr = [[AppDelegate getDelegate].managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];
                if ([arr count]) {
                    ((EmployeeCD*)arr.lastObject).photo = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
                    [[AppDelegate getDelegate] saveContext];
                }
            });
         }
         else
         {
             UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
             UIImage *img = [UIImage imageFromColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];
             UIImage *scaledImage = [img imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200)];
             UIImage *roundImage = [UIImage roundImage:scaledImage imageView:imgView];
             self.photo = roundImage;

             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"IMAGE_COULDNT_DOWNLOAD" object:self];
         }
     }];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, you violate iOS MVC rules
[MVC in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html)